# question on conversion of depth image

Tags: ros, image, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a depth image (128, 414, 3) type 64FC3.   I could like to convert this to be acceptable to send to rtabmap_ros/point_cloud_xyzrgb .  However I am not sure how to covert this image into an acceptable form.  Has anyone encounted an issue like this and can suggest a solution other then manually doing the point cloud conversion.

```
new2 = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(depth_image,  "bgr8")  
encoding specified as bgr8, but image has incompatible type 64FC3
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268588/question-on-conversion-of-depth-image/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I worked it out...all three channels where the same...so I just grabbed one and was able to do a astype(np.float32) on it.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0